Map does not show anything
var toDoList = [
    { AS4026: "7am-exercise; 8am-eat; 9am-school" },
    { p2: "12pm-lunch; 1pm-see friends" },
    { p3: "6pm-dinner; 8pm-drink medicines; 10pm-sleep" }
];

<div>
    {cart?.sku} {/* print "AS4026" */}

    {toDoList.map((item, index) => (                                                     
        <div key={index}>{item?.cart?.sku?.split(";").map(toDo => (                                                    
            <div key={toDo}>
                <input type="radio" name="p1" value={toDo} onChange={() => changeID(toDo)} />{toDo}
            </div>
        ))}</div>
    ))}
</div>

How come the toDoList.map shows nothing?
The following code works. But I need to replace AS4026 with cart.sku.
 <div>
                                                {cart?.sku} {/* print "AS4026" */}

                                                {toDoList.map((item, index) => (
                                                    <div key={index}>{item.AS4026?.split(";").map(toDo => (
                                                        <div key={toDo}>
                                                            <input type="radio" name="p1" value={toDo} onChange={() => changeID(toDo)} />{toDo}
                                                        </div>
                                                    ))}</div>
                                                ))}
                                            </div>


It doesn't have cart object in toDolist item

The following code work. But I need to replace AS4026 with cart.sku. {toDoList.map((item, index) => (
{item.AS4026?.split(";").map(toDo => (     .......................................

right now, your code is attempting to read "cart" on each item in toDoList.  no item in toDoList has a "cart" property.  if "cart" is defined elsewhere and you are trying to read a property matching the cart's "sku" property, the syntax would be:
<div>
    {cart?.sku} {/* print "AS4026" */}

    {toDoList.map((item, index) => (                                                     
        <div key={index}>{item[cart?.sku]?.split(";").map(toDo => (                                                    
            <div key={toDo}>
                <input type="radio" name="p1" value={toDo} onChange={() => changeID(toDo)} />{toDo}
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    ))}
</div>

